# how to enable req._reusedSocket in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, request

I want to know how to enable `req._reusedSocket` in my Node.js HTTP request.

I'd like to Node.js `request` module to retry when ECONNRESET error occurred.

However, I couldn't find anything related to enabling `req._reusedSocket`.

I tried to enable `forever: true` options, but it didn't work.

In request module code is here

https://github.com/request/request/blob/df346d8531ac4b8c360df301f228d5767d0e374e/request.js#L869

What is `req._reusedSocket` and when it's changed to `true`? And what should I do for it?